# How to use previously acquired data in the GraphQL query?

Tags: graphql, hasura

Let's say we have two entities.

- `users` that has `uuid`, `name` and `age`
- `users_books` that has `user_uuid`, `book_id` and `recommended_age`.

`user_uuid` was added as foreign key pointing to `uuid` in `Users`

Using user name I want to get all the books that that user reads and have recommended age equal to users age.

Following query will get me all the books that user reads

```
query getUserBooks($uuid: uuid!) {
  users_by_pk(uuid: $uuid) {
    uuid
    name
    age
    users_books() {
       book_id
       recommended_age
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the query I am trying to create:

```
query getUserBooksWithRestrictedAge($uuid: uuid!) {
  users_by_pk(uuid: $uuid) {
    uuid
    name
    age
    users_books(where:{recommended_age:{_eq: *WHAT_SHOULD_GO_HERE?*}}) {
       book_id
       recommended_age      
    }
  }
}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasura supports columns comparison operators only when setting permissions.  To accomplish what you need you have to create a view.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users_books_by_age AS 
  SELECT * from users_books
```

Set the relationships between the view, user and books table. In the Hasura view permission builder filter the age comparing the columns. Something like

```
{
  user: {
    age: {
     _ceq: recommended_age
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can run your query like:

```
query getUserBooks($uuid: uuid!) {
  users_by_pk(uuid: $uuid) {
    uuid
    name
    age
    users_books_by_age {
       book_id
       recommended_age
    }
  }
}
```

Another solution would be to create a computed field. Something like:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION author_full_name(user_row user)
RETURNS SETOF users_books AS $$
  SELECT * FROM users_books where recommended_age = user_row.age
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

I hope that helps.